# Change EditorFor in time of change input

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to change Editorfor that display already data from database when i change input 
i will take output of input and split it and put result in 2 EditorFor

```
<input type="text" value="Set Date" id="reservationtim onchange=myFunction()>

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "startDate" })

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } , id = "endDate" })
```

and the function :

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
   var date = document.getElementById("reservationtime").value;
   var res = date.split("-");
   model => model.StartDate = res[0];
   document.getElementById("startDate") = res[0];
   document.getElementById("endDate") = res[1];
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the element reference itself to the value you want. Rather you need to set the `value` attribute of the element reference:

```
document.getElementById("startDate").value = res[0];
```

Also, it looks like you're trying to mix server-side and client-side code here. Remember that JavaScript is not processed until the document has already been processed by the server and returned to the client. Once you're client-side, all that exists is just the DOM, which is created by the browser based on the HTML document the server sent down. In other words, the fact that you used `EditorFor` or whatever is completely lost. All you have is the result (i.e. HTML) of that call to `EditorFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You should first correct your HTML, as some attributes are not specified correctly.

```
<input type="text" value="Set Date" id="reservationtime" onchange="myFunction()">

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control" } )

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate,  new { @class = "form-control" }  )
```

I don't know why you are explicitly setting id for above two editors. they by default take property name as ID. so I would suggest following script for it.

```
    <script>
       function myFunction() {
       var date = document.getElementById("reservationtime").value;
       var res = date.split("-");
       model => model.StartDate = res[0];
      if(res.length>1) {
       document.getElementById("StartDate").value = res[0];
       document.getElementById("EndDate").value = res[1]; 
      // if you still want to set ID properties instead of using default use  following
      //   document.getElementById("StartDate").value = res[0];
     //   document.getElementById("EndDate").value = res[1]; 
     }



      }
    </script>
```