# ASP.NET MVC get input id to controller to make some changes before save model in database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image] i get date from cshtml as [StartDate - EndDate]
and the date in data base is split as start date as field and end date 
i want to get this date in controller and split them before saveChanges in data base

cshtml code :

```
    <div>        
       <input type="text" value='@Model.StartDate - @Model.EndDate' class="form-control pull-right" id="reservationtime" >
   </div>
```

and controller code :

```
  public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PerformanceId,EventId,VenueId,Score,Name,Image,Description,StartDate,EndDate,Facebook,Website,Views,IsClosedBooking,IsVisible,IsFeatured,Deleted,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,ModifiedOn,ModifiedBy")] Performance performance)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(performance).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
  return View(performance);
    }
```

Comment: To which property in the `Performance` class would you like to bind this value?

Comment: startdate and end date @Developer

Comment: either you can do it the way you already did in your another question using javascript.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809962/change-editorfor-in-time-of-change-input 
OR you have to write your own model binder to do this operation 
OR you have to get this value to server side as string => split it=> assingn it as you need

Comment: Create two hidden fields, one with name StartDate and other with name EndDate and assign the values accordingly. These values will be available in the controller when you post the form. `<input type="hidden" name="StartDate" value="@Model.StartDate" /><input type="hidden" name="EndDate" value="@Model.EndDate" />`

Comment: @Developer it's a good idea but ca i split date in html i try to do it by javascript but it didn't work

Comment: I've updated my comment with sample code. I'm hoping that you are doing a form submit and not ajax post.

Comment: I would recommend creating a class that represents the model, rather than passing the EF entity directly to the UI.  The reason being is that you can achieve what you are trying to do more easily if it wasn't the direct entity (you could create a ReservationTime property in the view model, and then calculate in the controller, rather than the UI).

Comment: sorry i try to catch The easiest solution because i'm new in mvc @Brian Mains thx for your help

Comment: sorry edit post to what @AlexeiLevenkov , ?

Comment: Sorry, need more coffee - it was @developer comment with code. Not sure why they don't want to provide an answer.

Comment: how can i make form to submit sorry ,@Developer

Comment: How are you hitting the `Edit` method? Is it on the Submit click?

Comment: yes my code is so huge in the last i hit submit button

Comment: Yup, then hidden fields should work.

Answer (score 1):

Create two hidden fields, one with name `StartDate` and other with name `EndDate` and assign the values accordingly. These values will be available in the controller when you post the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="StartDate" value="@Model.StartDate" />
<input type="hidden" name="EndDate" value="@Model.EndDate" />
```

Comment: this wil not modified with new value

Comment: What is the new value you expect?

Comment: i put an image to my post can you look at my post please , thanks @Developer

Comment: by default it generate - between start and end date i want satrt date and end date sperated

Comment: Ooh gotcha... So on clicking on `Apply` button after selecting the date, you can set the value to those hidden fields using jQuery/JavaScript. Though I'm not sure what control are you using for datepicker... The theory is, model binding in MVC is done via matching the element name with the property name. So if you have those hidden fields values updated according to the date picker selection, that should work

Comment: i only put " - "  to bind date from database but i cant set new value when i change it from calendar

Comment: It's getting real late here ~11.30 pm... I can't help without knowing about the datepicker control you are using. May be I'll get you answered tomorrow if you don't resolve this by that time.

Comment: i use daterangepicker @Developer

Comment: thank you very much , i really Sorry for the disturbance

Comment: Glad I helped. it was never a disturbance - it was getting late here and my kid was crying, so had to do a hard stop :)

Answer (score 0):

i reach to my answer i will use the event of daterangepaker 
when i click apply i will split the date

```
$('#daterange').daterangepicker();
$('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
   var date = document.getElementById("reservationtime").value;
var res = date.split("-");
document.getElementById("startDate").value = res[0];
document.getElementById("endDate").value = res[1];
});
```